# Go error in Docker: "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

Tags: go, https, certificate, keycloak, ca

When connecting to a KeyCloak instance via HTTPS, the Go client gives this error:

> x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

It works on my machine (c), but fails in Docker.
The server's certificate is valid, from LetsEncrypt.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to add more CA certificates into your Docker image.
In Alpine, do this:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
```

If you have a multi-stage Docker build with `golang`+`debian`, this might help:

```
FROM golang:1.19.3-bullseye AS builder
RUN go build ...
#...more build steps...


FROM debian:bullseye

# Get more CA certificates
COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/

#...more steps..
```